# ASP.net Routing - using database queries in order to determine the physical file, and add extra route data from query results

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-routing

My question is regarding Page Routing in an ASP.net (VB) Web Forms website.

I need to route to 2 .aspx pages in multiple ways e.g.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("SEO", "{Title}/{Id}", "~/PageA.aspx")
routes.MapPageRoute("Catalogue", "Issue{IssueNumber}-{PageNumber}", "~/PageA.aspx")
```

but I need to implement some logic involving database queries (LINQ to SQL) on both routes e.g.

Route 1) Check a bit field, if false then physical file = PageA.aspx, true then PageB.aspx

Route 2) Lookup IssueNumber and PageNumber, retrieve PageId and add to RouteData, set physical file = PageA.aspx

I think the best way of doing this, is to implement an IRouteHandler class but I've not been able to determine:

- Where to write the database queries in such class
- How to set the physical file in the class
- Where/how to add a new value to the route data i.e. PageId
- Where to check that Id and Number fields are actually integers (constraints?)

I can't find any useful VB.net documentation, any suggestions?

If not I'm going to have to resort to an intermediate .aspx page i.e. Transfer.aspx and then do the database queries and then store return values in session variables and then do a `Server.Transfer(PageA.aspx)`, but this seems like an old-fashioned and inelegant way of doing it. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing your own IRouteHandler I'd suggest implementing your Route class. Override GetRouteData and setup the RouteData object that you return according to your needs.

> Where to write the database queries in such class

As mentioned above, GetRouteData is the place you are looking for.

> How to set the physical file in the class

On the RouteData object you return, set RouteHandler to a new PageRouteHandler instance. You can pass the physical path to PageRouteHandler's constructor.

> Where/how to add a new value to the route data i.e. PageId

Use the Values property of the RouteData object.

> Where to check that Id and Number fields are actually integers (constraints?)

This should be done with route constraints. The sixth parameter to MapPageRoute for example is a RouteValueDictionary with contraints. To simple check that a parameter is an integer, use a regular expression, like so:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("RouteName", _
  "product/{id}", "~/Products.aspx", _
  True, New RouteValueDictionary(), _
  New RouteValueDictionary() From { {"id", "\d+"} })
```

See the "\d+" at the end? This is the regular expression that the id parameter needs to match.

If you need more complex constraints you can do that as well, see e.g. http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I never thought of it that way. So all I need to do is implement my own Route Class by inheritance? and then override the relevant members?

Comment: So does that mean that route objects are created every time a user accesses another page?

Comment: The Route objects are added to the RouteCollection only once (typically during Application_Start), but for each request a RouteData object is created.

Comment: I think the problem is that RouteData does not let you set the values it is read only. I thought about storing the PageId in a DataToken but I'm pretty sure that because Route objects are set during Application_Start then they will not change from page to page.

Comment: You can't set the Values property, that's true. But you can modify it's content, like routeData.Values.Add("PageId", myPageId) etc. And as I said, the Route object won't change, but the RouteData object you create is new for every request.

Comment: So does the GetRouteData method automatically get called on each request?

Comment: Yes. It's called on each route up to the first route that does not return null. Here's a quick example of how to implement what I mean (this one handles the "Issue{IssueNumber}-{PageNumber}" route): https://gist.github.com/1903446 You might also want to override GetVirtualPath if you want to cover the opposite case (create the URL from route data).

Comment: Oh, I forgot to show how to use it: https://gist.github.com/1903507. The first parameter is the route to match, the second defines the defaults and the third the constraints.

Comment: Wow that is fantastic thank you so much... I was totally on the wrong track there with the IRouteHandler - I blame clear as mud MSDN documentation. Thanks for the code, during these comments I've been reading the MSDN documentation on the Route class and things were slowly falling into place but honestly I don't think I would have been able to implement it without your code. Thanks. :)

Comment: Hehe, you're welcome. I was incidentally implementing my own routes for a CMS I'm working the other day, so I had my head still wrapped around the topic.